# xsl key match to return specific value

Tags: xslt-1.0

input:

```
<DS>
<TL>
    <msg>
        <output_getquerydata>
            <queries>
                <query name="q1">
                    <parameters>
                        <parameter name="id">906OREA</parameter>
                    </parameters>
                    <results>
                        <record>
                            <column name="actionState">sdss</column>
                        </record>
                    </results>
                </query>
                <query name="q2">
                    <parameters>
                        <parameter name="resCode">CTL</parameter>
                        <parameter name="prodCode">89CMID</parameter>
                        <parameter name="pos">1,2,4,3</parameter>
                    </parameters>
                    <results>
                        <record id="1">
                            <column name="position">1</column>
                            <column name="ExternalProductId"/>
                        </record>
                        <record id="9">
                            <column name="position"/>
                            <column name="ExternalProductId">316442</column>
                        </record>
                    </results>
                </query>
                <query name="q2">
                    <parameters>
                        <parameter name="resCode">CTL</parameter>
                        <parameter name="prodCode">91VPRM</parameter>
                        <parameter name="pos">1,2,4,3</parameter>
                    </parameters>
                    <results>
                        <record id="1">
                            <column name="position"/>
                            <column name="ExternalProductId">316495</column>
                        </record>
                    </results>
                </query>
            </queries>
        </output_getquerydata>
    </msg>
    <TL>
        <ArticleNr>89CMID</ArticleNr>
    </TL>
    <TL>
        <ArticleNr>89CMID</ArticleNr>
    </TL>
    <TL>
        <ArticleNr>89CMID</ArticleNr>
    </TL>
    <TL>
        <ArticleNr>91VPRM</ArticleNr>
    </TL>
</TL>
</DS>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:key name="Article" match="tLoading" use="./ArticleNr"/>
<xsl:key name="prod" match="query[@name='q2']/results/record" use="./column[@name='ExternalProductId'][node()]"/>
<xsl:template match="DS">
    <msglist>
        <xsl:for-each select="./TL[./msg/output_getquerydata/queries/query/results/record/column[@name='actionState'] !='finished'] ">
            <xsl:variable name="distinctArticle" select="//TL[string(ArticleNr)][count(. | key('Article',ArticleNr)[1]) = 1]"/>
            <msg>
                <xsl:for-each select="$distinctArticle">
                    <load-part>
                    <!--I need here the value from column[@name='ExtPR'], that has parameter[@name='prodCode']=the current TL articleNr node.
                     -->
                        <productId>
                            <xsl:value-of select="key('prod',column[@name='ExternalProductId'])"/>
                        </productId>
                        <!--something-->
                    </load-part>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </msg>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </msglist>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired OUTPUT:

```
<msglist>
<msg>
    <load-part>
        <productId>316442</productId>
    </load-part>
    <load-part>
        <productId>316442</productId>
    </load-part>
    <load-part>
        <productId>316442</productId>
    </load-part>
    <load-part>
        <productId>316495</productId>
    </load-part>
</msg>
</msglist>
```

I need in the `productID` node, the value from `column[@name='ExternalProductId']`, that has `parameter[@name='prodCode']=the current <TL><ArticleNr>` node.
I know that this 'for each' code that I've put, returns only two values, because i'm searching for the distinct values, so I was thinking that I will try with a key, but i'm not sure what I am missing.

Thank you

---

edited for the correct output values

Comment: Is your desired output correct? All that is showing is the existing values from `ArticleNr`, and so does not need any lookups at all.

Comment: This is part of a bigger XSL, basically I need the lookup because I could have different values in ArticleNr which don't match the 'prodCode'

Comment: I'm sorry, Tim, you were right, it had the wrong values :) I've edited it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your `Article` key looks wrong (in the context of your question) as there are no `tLoading` elements in your XML. So it should be this...

```
<xsl:key name="Article" match="TL" use="ArticleNr"/>
```

But to answer your direct question, you need to define your `prod` key like so

```
<xsl:key name="prod" 
         match="query[@name='q2']/results/record" 
         use="../../parameters/parameter[@name='prodCode']"/>
```

Then, to look it up, do this...

```
 <xsl:value-of select="key('prod', ArticleNr)/column[@name='ExternalProductId']"/>
```

Or maybe this, as they "q2" query has two ExternalProductIds...

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('prod', ArticleNr)/column[@name='ExternalProductId'][. != '']"/>
```

Try this XSLT (which retains your distinct check, and so only outputs two rows)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:key name="Article" match="TL" use="ArticleNr"/>
<xsl:key name="prod" match="query[@name='q2']/results/record" use="../../parameters/parameter[@name='prodCode']"/>

<xsl:template match="DS">
    <msglist>
        <xsl:for-each select="./TL[./msg/output_getquerydata/queries/query/results/record/column[@name='actionState'] !='finished'] ">
            <xsl:variable name="distinctArticle" select="//TL[string(ArticleNr)][count(. | key('Article',ArticleNr)[1]) = 1]"/>
            <msg>
                <xsl:for-each select="$distinctArticle">
                    <load-part>
                        <productId>
                            <xsl:value-of select="ArticleNr" /> 
                            <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="key('prod', ArticleNr)/column[@name='ExternalProductId'][. != '']"/>
                        </productId>
                    </load-part>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </msg>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </msglist>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```